# How do I click a usercontrols child in designer?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I'm having a bit of trouble with creating one of my custom controls.

What I've got is a listbox within a usercontrol, and I need to be able to click on the lists items while still in the designer. This would make it act much like the tabcontrol.

I haven't dealt much with usercontrols but I've tried catching some overide events without success.

```
    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DesignMode)
        {
            InvokeOnClick(listBox1, e);
        }
        base.OnClick(e);
    }
```

I haven't been able to find anything on the web.. Any ideas on how I can do this?

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: I assume you're talking about WinForms, but you might want to clarify. I'm having a hard time imagining why this would be useful - can you explain why you need this behavior?

Comment: I've created an assistant usercontrol for the tabcontrol that allows you to view tabs and change tabs of the tabcontrol via the list. It uses binding source etc. Much like the options window of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Bradley: thanks for pointing me in the right direction

You will need to write a ControlDesigner class, then use it in a `[Designer( ... )]` attribute on your UserControl.

See the example here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sycctd1z(v=VS.90).aspx

For the actual click:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.design.controldesigner.gethittest(v=VS.90).aspx

The ControlDesigner has a `protected bool GetHitTest(Point point)` method - you can implement this in your ControlDesigner and return `true` when you want your control to handle a click, based on the click's location on the screen.

Comment: Thanks, that really led me in the right direction! Once I implemented the gethittest I was able to receive click events on all the children on the control. I then used the boolean DesignMode to check if in design mode and got the index of the listitem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found this link that says you need to implement a custom designer to get the desired behavior, and explains how to make it happen.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/winforms/thread/0b6ed0cb-907c-4733-b245-ae5d0b0e6606

Comment: Thanks for your help! I could only award winner to one answer, but thanks for pointing sq33G in the right way. I +1'd you to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get away with catching the MouseDown event in the custom control and forwarding it on to the inner control.  I'm not sure how MouseDown behaves in design mode though.

Comment: Thats kind of what I was attempting to do, but I don't know enough about working with usercontrols to get it to work.