# Add controls to Panel within custom control, in design mode

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

My control contains a panel (it will have multiple, but I've simplified it for the sake of solving this problem) which has dock set to fill.

The issue I'm having is that at design time, any other controls are added to the control, rather than the panel within in the control.

Comment: @GrantWinney  That's correct

Comment: Add the Panel as a child control of the custom control and then add further controls to the panel?

Comment: @adaam It's added.
I can see it (gave it a bright pink background - just to be sure :P), and add controls dynamically.
It's just in design mode when dragging controls onto it, that they're put into the control itself, rather than the panel within the control.

Comment: @mhorne Okay well I have no experience of using design mode in this manner as I always add controls programatically. Sorry

Comment: This might be a long shot, but isn't there a drop event that you can catch inside the parent uc, and redirect the drag/drop to drop in the desired panel?

Comment: @LouisvanTonder I tried intercepting with ControlAdded, but I then can't add the control to the panel ("child is not a child control of this parent") - tried lots of things to fix that but got nowhere.  I don't think it'd have changed the designer code anyway, would it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762397/how-do-i-click-a-usercontrols-child-in-designer . Maybe that can help.